# Почему объект значений формы пуст?

Tags: angular2

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Я пытаюсь написать кастомный валидатор для реактивной формы.
html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="line">
    <input class="email" id="email" placeholder="email" type="email" formControlName="email">
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <input class="password" id="password" placeholder="Пароль" type="password" formControlName="password">
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <input class="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Пароль снова" type="password" formControlName="password2">
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <input class="name" id="name" placeholder="Имя" type="text" formControlName="name">
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <input class="checkbox" id="agree" type="checkbox" formControlName="agree">
    <label for="agree">Согласие на обработку персональных данных</label>
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <button class="submit" id="submit" type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">зарегистрироваться</button>
  </div>
```

component:

```
private form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    const this_ = this;

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'email':      new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      'password':   new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
      'password2':  new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), this_.comparePasswords]),
      'name':       new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      'agree':      new FormControl(false, [Validators.requiredTrue])
    });
  }

  comparePasswords(c: FormControl) {
    console.log(c);

    const hashStr = Md5.hashStr(c.value.password);
    const hashStr2 = Md5.hashStr(c.value.password2);

    console.log(hashStr, hashStr2);

    return (hashStr === hashStr2) ? null : {
      comparePasswords: {
        valid: false
      }
    };
  }
```

Все импорты какие нужно подключил. После загрузки странички консоль браузера сразу выводит объект формы, в котором объект value равен null.

Соответственно я не могу в функции comparePasswords сделать проверку.

Кроме того консоль выводит такую ошибку:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null

А при попытке заполнять поля формы консоль выводит такое:

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
```

Скажите пожалуйста как поправить валидацию(без попытки кастомной валидаци this_.comparePasswords проблем нет)

[тут живой пример](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2k8rq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день!
Если я Вас правильно понял, то попробуйте заменить инициализацию формы каким то значением, например пустой строкой.

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  'email':      new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  'password':   new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
  'password2':  new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), this_.comparePasswords]),
  'name':       new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  'agree':      new FormControl(false, [Validators.requiredTrue])
});
```

}